# Subsurface Between Two Meshes

Tags: modifiers, objects

I'm working on a model of an aircraft that will eventually be animated with details like landing gear doors, and am using a Subsurface Modifier. Most everything is going well, however I've run into a problem:

Whenever I have two separate objects that need to follow the same lines (IE, the landing gear doors), the Subsurface Modifier does NOT apply equally to both objects. If I join the door mesh to the fuselage mesh it's fine, but as soon as I separate the doors from the fuselage it breaks the lines:

[image: Fuselage Line Intact]

[image: Fuselage Line Broken]

Obviously, this is going to be a serious issue. I CAN get around it by applying the Subsurface Modifier FIRST and THEN separate the gear bay doors from the fuselage mesh, however this will then mean working directly with the higher-poly mesh that I'm using the modifier to avoid in the first place.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening when I separate the objects?

Comment: I think control loops will help and you might consider uploading the .blend file to PasteAll.org with a link pasted here so people can experiment with different techniques on the model before answering.

Comment: A file would really help to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Rule #1 of high poly modelling: Never let subsurf do the work for you. If you need a curved shape, model a curved shape. Modelling it all blocky and leaving it up to the subsurf to make the curved shape means you have no control and will run into issues like this.

Comment: Try applying a single subdivision level of subsurf to get some more vertices to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up just applying the SubSurf modifier and creating the gear doors from that. Thanks for the input, tho.